# How to make all the web page within iframe open in same tab?

Tags: css, iframe, web, html

I have an iframe within which I open a third party website. Few links in the webpage opens in new tab. How do I override this option and make sure all the links open in the same iframe?

## Sample Code

Your browser doesn't support iframes

Comment: Provide your code you tried to figure out

Comment: we can help you, please put your code ,

Answer (score 2):

**This code can't be tested on an offline page. You will need to test it within live page**

Suppose this is your iframe.

```
 <iframe src='give_your_url_here.com'/>
```

Put the below code instead of your iframe and replace the variable 'url' with your required url.

This is not a proper method, but this is the only solution to your situation.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="queryResultContainer"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = 'give_your_url_here.com';//without http://
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/go?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        var aa = data.contents;
        $('#queryResultContainer').html(aa + "<script> setInterval(function () { $('#queryResultContainer').find('a').removeAttr('target');}, 200);</script" + ">");
    });
</script>
```

If your site is HTTPS then change

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com....
```

To

```
$.getJSON('https://anyorigin.com....
```

Comment: it throws an error Anonymous apps are not allowed. Must have a valid referrer URL. If you are developing locally, try throwing your files up on dropbox. Whereas in the http://anyorigin.com/ it works fine and shows the website in the output.

Comment: Also the website is an https one.

Comment: This will not work in offline site. You have to test it in live site.

Comment: @Divya Krishnan I have updated my answer for https. The question you posted is still incomplete, not enough information. My answer was based on the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If the links on the third party website are programmed to open in new windows / tabs, you have no way of modifying that code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to to handle this. Is there a possibility to have a small widget that pops up in all the tabs that open , so that when I click it goes back to the home page.